DHCP relay not sending responses to client from S2S VPN
I have a DHCP server that is connected to a router(R1) which has a s2s VPN connection (interface tun0) with another router(R2) where the DHCP client is on, I set up DHCP relay on R2 using isc-dhcp-relay
# What servers should the DHCP relay forward requests to?
SERVERS="dhcp-server ip"
# On what interfaces should the DHCP relay (dhrelay) serve DHCP requests?
INTERFACES="ens33"
# Additional options that are passed to the DHCP relay daemon?
OPTIONS=""

ens33 is the interface that is connected to the client
The issue is DHCP offer is reaching R2 but it is not sending the DHCP offer to the client
